# How to access body parameters while using multipart form data in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

There were lots of similar questions related to mine, but no one gonna clear my doubt.

So,whenever I write

```
<form id="form" action="/" method="post" role="form">
```

and in my backend code, Let say I write

```
 console.log(req.body.name)
```

I got the data correctly, but if I add enctype = multipart/form-data as

```
<form id="form" action="/" method="post" role="form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

I got req.body.name as 'undefined' or body parameters as 'undefined'.

Is there any way to get the body parameters While using  enctype="multipart/form-data?
Please Help!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63443875/13126651 follow this answer just add middleware to parse your req, `const app = express(); app.use(express.json());` do upvote my answer if it helped you so that it may help others in future

Comment: use can use `multer` module, you can access variables using `req.body` and uploaded data from `req.file` or `req.files` depending on single or multiple files

Answer (score 2):

`enctype="multipart/form-data"` is not natively handled by `express`, you can use `multer` to handle `multipart/form-data`

```
npm install --save multer
```

[Multer NPM](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer)

```
const multer  = require('multer');
let upload = multer({ dest: 'uploads/' }); //<-- Could be any folder
router.post('/', upload, function (req, res) {
    console.log('Body- ' + JSON.stringify(req.body));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In an alternative way, you can use a formidable module from the NPM.

[Npm formidable](https://www.npmjs.com/package/formidable)

> ```
> npm install --save formidable
> ```

```
const multer  = require('formidable');

router.post('/', upload, function (req, res) {
    const form = formidable({ multiples: true });
    form.parse(req, (err, fields, files) => {
      console.log('fields: ', fields);
      console.log('files: ', files);
     // enter code here
    });
});
```